# Do I need to bind to a component to use the apollo react client even if it has no UI?

Tags: react-apollo

I'm doing some business logic around an implementation of the Auth0 lock widget and need to call some graphql mutations to sign in.  In this case there is no UI to render since it's simply a call to Auth0's lock.show() method.  However, looking at all the apollo client examples with react - the graphql method seems to bind the functions to a component.

- Can I call a gql mutation directly without binding it to a react component?
- What's the best way to get the client from the ApolloProvider if I'm not in a component?  Is there a static singleton instance i can reference from ApolloProvider or do I need to pass the client reference from the root application compoment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `withApollo()` decorator exported from `apollo-client` to access the client as a prop inside a component. The `ApolloProvider` exposes the `client` to its child components through context. The `withApollo()` higher-order component accesses the `client` on context and passes it to its child as a prop.

So, if the `auth.lock()` function is being triggered by some type of UI interaction or one of the React lifecycle methods, you can access the `client` in that component and either call the mutation directly in the component or pass it as an argument through to the function that calls `auth.lock()`.

However, since you want to access the `client` outside of the React tree, you have to access the `client` in a different way.

Alternatively, you can export the same `client` that you pass as a prop to `ApolloProvider` and import it wherever you need to use it in the app. Note, this singleton pattern won't work with server-side rendering. Example:

**root.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import routes from './routes';

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  }
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface
});
export const store = configureStore(browserHistory, client);
export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

export default function Root() {
  <ApolloProvider client={client} store={store}>
    <Router
      history={history}
      routes={routes}
    />
  </ApolloProvider>
}
```

**some-other-module.js**

```
import { client } from 'app/root';

export default function login(username, password) {
  return client.mutate({
    // ...mutationStuff
  });
}
```

Comment: can i do client.query the same way ?

Answer (score 2):

You can import `ApolloProvider` like this:

`import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";`